# Web API Controller not found when class is generic

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm trying to use a Generic Controller in my Web API. My goal, which I am currently failing at, is to pass in an object from my front end that will have say a typeId.  Based on this typeId I was going to use a factory to inject the correct class implementation of a generic interface.  I believe my Factory, Interface and Service is correct, but for some reason when I add a Generic to the API I am getting a 404. It works without a generic and just a test method. I am using autofac for my IoC registration.

API Controller:

```
public class ListItemsController<T> : ApiControllerBase
{
    private readonly IListItemsService<T> _service;

    public ListItemsController(int listItemTypeId)
    {
        _service = ListItemsFactory<T>.InitializeService(listItemTypeId);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{listItemTypeId: int}")]
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _service.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class ListItemsFactory<T>
{
    public ListItemsFactory(IPrimaryContext context) : base()
    {
    }

    public static IListItemsService<T> InitializeService(int listItemType)
    {
        switch (listItemType)
        {
            case 1: return (IListItemsService<T>)
                new FloorTypeService(new PrimaryContext());
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IListItemsService<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Save(T obj);
    T GetById(int id);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

Error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/listitems/test'. No type was found that matches the controller named 'listitems'.

I'm not sure what piece I'm missing here.  I'm using routing attributes but here is my API config:

```
private static void SetupRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}",
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

Comment: I'm posting a direct answer to your question, but what is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish? Maybe there's a way you can avoid using generics.

Comment: Sure I'm open to that.  I have 11 entities that are basically ID and Name that will run CRUD against.  I didn't want to have 11 Endpoint duplication's so I thought passing in a typeId on a generic object would let me have 1 controller that then calls the correct service class.  This service class would handle the correct EF context mapping.  So say in my sample typeId 1 is passed in with a generic object.  I know that is a floortype so I implement that service.  Then the API calls that implementation for the endpoint I need.

Comment: I've added an answer on how to accomplish what you're asking. Having said that, in your case, i would considre just having  "duplicated" endpoints. Even though you might not have any specific rules for these types right now, it doesn't mean you won't have them in the feature, and having everything handled by a single controller might make it more difficult to handle special cases down the line.

Comment: It surprises me people keep asking why someone would want to use generics. The answer is obvious. We dont want to duplicate boiler plate code for the 5-10 methods that are repeated for each object that needs CRUD. 

The problem lies in the fact that you cant seem to extend the generic and add controller specific routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of resolving the type and trying to map to the right Controller, you also can create a Controller for each Type, which inherits from your GenericController. Then you don't have to copy the Code, but have a Controller for each Type, where you can route to by RouteAttribute.:

```
public class ListItemsController<T> : ApiControllerBase
{
    //Properties/Fields should be protected to can be accessed from InstanceController.
    protected readonly IListItemsService<T> _service;
    // I think listItemTypeId is not necessary, if generic-type T is used?
    public ListItemsController()
    {
        _service = ListItemsFactory<T>.InitializeService();
    }

    [HttpGet] // No need for RouteAttribute, because it will be in InstanceController.
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _service.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")] // This can rest here, because you want to use it.
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok();
    }



}
```

The implemented InstanceController can look like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{controller}")]
public class FloorItemsController  ListItemsController<Floor> 
{
    // delegate the Constructor-call to base()
    public ListItemsController()
        :base()
    {

    }

     // No need to reimplement Methods.
}
```

The RouteConfiguration should be set back to default, because RouteAttributes are set for this.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly for my scenario!  Even fixes the need for an additional arg to determine the type in the factory.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you'll need to do is to replace the controller activator, with a custom implementation.

First, createa  class that implements the `IHttpControllerSelector` interface. Take a look [at this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/08/22/customizing-web-api-controller-selector/) for some of the thing you should be aware before creating a custom activator. At the bottom there's a link to some code example of a custom implmentation.

Now, this depends on what your rules will actually be, but for perfomance reasons,you should try to build a solution that always map the same controller name to the same closed type of your generic controller type. A simple implementation for your case would look something like this:

```
public HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();
    if (routeData == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    //get the generyc type of your controller
    var genericControllerType = typeof(ListItemsController<>);

    // Get the route value from which you'll get the type argument from your controller.
    string typeParameterArgument = GetRouteVariable<string>(routeData, 'SomeKeyUsedToDecideTheClosedType');
    Type typeArgument = //Somehow infer the generic type argument,  form your route value based on your needs
    Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(typeArgument) };
    //obtain the closed generyc type
    var t = genericControllerType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);            

    //configuration must be an instance of HttpConfiguration, most likeley you would inject this on the activator constructor on the config phase
    new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, t.Name, t); 

}
```

Finally, on your ApiConfig class you'll need to add this line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), 
        new MyOwnActivatior());
```

I can't test this code right now, so it might need some tweaking, but hopefully this will guide you on the right direction. Do take notice of the link i pasted above, since there are important considerations you'll need to take into account before implementing a custom activator. Also, check the code example linked on that post to see how to implement the `GetControllerMapping` method

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I will work through trying to implement it, but I'm curious about 1 thing.  Why does making the controller implementing a generic cause the need for this new ControllerDescriptor?  Does it impact how the routing configuration sees the type and the name conflicts with what it is expecting?

Comment: I'm a little bussy right now, but i'll try to give you a more comprhensive answer later. Yes, using a custom implementation for the ControllerSelector impacts the routing configuration. Basically, this is related to how the WebApi pipleine works. When a request is recived, based on the request data,  the framework needs to determine which controller type  will handle the request before instatating it. The default behaviour is to look for type named {controllerName}Controller, where controller  is the part of the route asigned for the controller name, which doesn't recognize generics.

Comment: The ControllerSelector is the extensibility point provided by the framwerok, where you can customize this behaviour. There's  another  extensibility point which is the type resolver, that could work for this case but i'm not quite sure if it'll work with generics. https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation.  I ended up going with the other suggestion but this was a very helpful learning experience.

Comment: I have been banging my head on the wall trying to get this to work. Finally I have an answer as to why creating generic controllers WONT work.  Its a shame, but the benefit of generics, in my case, does not justify installing a custom activator that may degrade performance.